# Determine if the whole system is LTI if one sub system is LTI and another is not

Tags: discrete-signals

Let T1 and T2 be two separate systems and T be the cascaded system:
[image]

Prove if the statement "T1 is LTl and T2 is not LTl, then T cannot be LTl" is correct

I would truly appreciate it if you could provide us with some hint. My intuition told me the statement is false, but I could not get any counter example

Comment: Perhaps you can add a few words to reveal to all readers as to why your intuition is telling you that the statement is false?

Comment: Hint: Proving that a system is "not LTI" amounts logically to proving that the system is either not linear or not time-invariant. Proving one or the other is sufficient.

Comment: It may be easier to think about the inverse. The inverse of  $A \land B \Rightarrow C$ is $\lnot C \Rightarrow \lnot A \lor \lnot B$, which in this case is the statement _"if $T$ is LTI, than either $T_1$ is not LTI or $T_2$ is LTI"_. We know that $T_1$ is LTI, so this equivalent to the statement that _"if $T$ is LTI, then $T_2$ is LTI"_. What does your intuition tell you about that statement? If you know that all of the properties of LTI systems apply to $T$, can you think of how to show whether they apply to $T_2$? Remember that $T$ _is just_ $T_2$ with an LTI system applied to its input.

Comment: Have you tried proving/disproving it using superposition?  Can you _show your work_?